# Is it possible to set the default frontend rule type?

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-ingress, traefik-ingress

https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/kubernetes/#general-annotations Says that the `traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rule-type` annotation **overrides** the **the default frontend rule type**.

Is there any way to *set the default frontend rule type* to `PathPrefixStrip` so I will not have to override it in every single Ingress definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in traefik 1.7 default fronted rule is hardcoded and not documented.
https://github.com/containous/traefik/blob/v1.7/provider/kubernetes/kubernetes.go#L48

```golang
    defaultFrontendRule        = "PathPrefix:/"
//...

                if len(frontend.Routes) == 0 {
                    frontend.Routes["/"] = types.Route{
                        Rule: defaultFrontendRule,
                    }
                }
//...
    templateObjects.Frontends[defaultFrontendName].Routes["/"] = types.Route{
        Rule: defaultFrontendRule,
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can use Traefik [Static](https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#static-traefik-configuration) configuration file and explicitly propagate global configuration for entrypoints, frontends and backends objects.

Static config applies Traefik settings at the `traefik-ingress-controller` initialization phase, thus all dynamically created sources, like K8s `Ingress` resources may override some key-value parameters as per [precedence](https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#static-traefik-configuration) order behavior.

Therefore, you might consider including [Matcher](https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#matchers) route rules via `PathPrefixStrip` parameter for the target [Frontends](https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#frontends) within a global configuration file, i.e:

```
[frontends]
  [frontends.frontend1]
  backend = "backend1"
    [frontends.frontend1.routes.test_1]
    rule = "PathPrefixStrip:/somepath"
```

More details about Traefik TOML file template and design you can find [here](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/file/#file-provider).